# If condition in CSHTML file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement

```
                                <div class="DDLabel">
                                Month:@Html.DropDownList("Month"new  SelectList(new List<object>
                                        {
                                        new { value = 1 , text = "Jan"},
                                        new { value = 2 , text = "Feb"},
                                        new { value = 3 , text = "Mar"},
                                        new { value = 4 , text = "Apr"},
                                        new { value = 5 , text = "May"},
                                        new { value = 6 , text = "Jun"},
                                        new { value = 7 , text = "Jul"},
                                        new { value = 8 , text = "Aug"},
                                        new { value = 9 , text =  "Sep"},
                                        new { value = 10 , text = "Oct"},
                                        new { value = 11, text = "Nov"},
                                        new { value = 12 , text = "Dec"},
                                        }, "value", "text", 1), new { @onchange = "e_date_changed();", @style = "width:66px" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="DDLabel">
                                    Day:@Html.DropDownList("Day", new SelectList(new List<object>
                                        {
                                        new { value =1, text = "1"},
                                        new { value =2, text = "2"},
                                        new { value =3 ,text ="3"},
                                        new { value =4, text = "4"},
                                        new { value =5, text = "5"},
                                        new { value =6, text = "6"},
                                        new { value =7, text = "7"},
                                        new { value =8, text = "8"},
                                        new { value =9, text = "9"},
                                        new { value =10, text = "10"},
                                        new { value =11, text = "11"},
                                        new { value =12, text = "12"},
                                        new { value =13, text = "13"},
                                        new { value =14, text = "14"},
                                        new { value =15, text = "15"},
                                        new { value =16, text = "16"},
                                        new { value =17, text = "17"},
                                        new { value =18, text = "18"},
                                        new { value =19, text = "19"},
                                        new { value =20, text = "20"},
                                        new { value =21, text = "21"},
                                        new { value =22, text = "22"},
                                        new { value =23, text = "23"},
                                        new { value =24, text = "24"},
                                        new { value =25, text = "25"},
                                        new { value =26, text = "26"},
                                        new { value =27, text = "27"},
                                        new { value =28, text = "28"},
                                        new { value =29, text = "29"},
                                        new { value =30, text = "30"},
                                        new { value =31, text = "31"},
                                        }, "value", "text", 1), new { @onchange = "e_date_changed();", @style = "width:66px" })
                                </div>
```

I want a if condition. By which user if user select April month then in next DropDownList must show only 30 day and if October then it should b 31 days. How can i do this and where should be this code placed?

Comment: This would be done in JavaScript, not in server-side code.  There would be a change event handler attached to the "month" drop down which would examine the updated value and modify the "day" drop down accordingly.  Why not use one of the many, many calendar or date picker tools already available?

Comment: It's freely available, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done in client-side code, not server-side code.  Since you mention jQuery in a comment, I'll assume the use of that.  You don't show the client-side markup, so for simplicity I'm also going to assume `id` attributes on the `select` elements.

First you'd need a change event handler for the "month" `select`, something like this:

```
$('#month').change(function () {
    var selectedMonth = $(this).val();
    // respond to the new value here
});
```

This will be invoked any time that `select` element's selected value changes.  Then within this function you'd respond to the new value and adjust the "day" `select` accordingly.  Since there isn't much of a pattern to month lengths, I imagine it would come down to a `switch` statement.  Something like:

```
switch (selectedMonth) {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        // 30 days
        break;
    case 2:
        // 28 or 29 days, good luck with that
        break;
    default:
        // 31 days
}
```

You can look up the logic for determining the number of days in February depending on the year.  It's usually every 4 years, but with some exceptions.

As for modifying the "day" `select`, there are some different approaches with that.  For example you might have a handful of distinctly different `select` elements for "day" which you style to show/hide so that only the "correct" one is displayed at any given time.  That might look like this:

```
$('#day28').hide();
$('#day29').hide();
$('#day30').hide();
$('#day31').show();
```

Or you might have some pre-defined HTML strings in the code which contain the `option` elements and you simply [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the entire set of elements each time.  That might look something like this:

```
$('#day option').remove();
$('#day').append(options31string);
```

Or perhaps some other approach to construct the `select` element.  Regardless of how you do it, the main point is that you'd modify it in response to the `change` event of the first `select` element.  This is often referred to as "cascading drop downs" (which you can search on Google for lots of other examples and plugins).

---

Though, honestly, just using something like [a date picker plugin](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default) sounds a heck of a lot easier.